# How to encode a MultiIDict in werkzeug 3.0

Tags: urlencode, werkzeug

I see [`url_encode`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/urls/#werkzeug.urls.url_encode) no longer is available in Werkzeug 3.0.

Replacing it with `urlencode` from `urllib.parse` won't work with lists e.g.

```
>>> from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
>>> d = MultiDict(('a', '1'), ('a', '2'))
>>> urlencode(d) #werkzeug url_encode returned 'a=1&a=2'
'a=1'
```

How do I url encode a `MultiDict` in Werkzeug 3.0 so I can use it as `x-www-form-urlencoded` data?

Answer (score 0):

Found myself the *not-so-intuitive-straightforward* answer:

```
>>> from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
>>> d = MultiDict(('a', '1'), ('a', '2'))
>>> urlencode(d.to_dict(flat=False), doseq=True)
'a=1&a=2'
```